# cross domain request using jquery ajax returns success but in error handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Following is my code to make a cross domain request. It goes into the error handler but says status is success and status is 200.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
        type: 'GET',
dataType: 'jsonp',
crossDomain:true,
cache: false,
success: function(res) {
     console.dir(res);
},
error: function(err){
     console.dir(err); //It goes here and abong other statusText: succes and status: 200
      }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the thrid party domain supports CORS?

Comment: no I am not. but without it I get access denied.

Comment: In that case the third party does not support CORS and you are being caught by the Same Origin Policy. You need to use a server side proxy to achieve what you need.

Comment: It is a html file I want to retrieve.
I have to add this information maybe it helps you to help me. when I use YQL to make cross domain request; if dataType is jsonp the result of the responseData is empty, if dataType is html but it retrieves .... yahoo:cout=0 ... nothing vlaueable